# Why is this Javascript much *slower* than its jQuery equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a HTML list of about 500 items and a "filter" box above it. I started by using jQuery to filter the list when I typed a letter (timing code added later):

```
$('#filter').keyup( function() {
    var jqStart = (new Date).getTime();

    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var $list = $('ul.ablist > li');

    $list.each( function() {
        if ( $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === -1 )
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    } );

    console.log('Time: ' + ((new Date).getTime() - jqStart));
} );
```

However, there was a couple of seconds delay after typing each letter (particularly the first letter). So I thought it may be slightly quicker if I used plain Javascript (I read recently that jQuery's `each` function is particularly slow). Here's my JS equivalent:

```
document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener( 'keyup', function () {
    var jsStart = (new Date).getTime();

    var search = this.value.toLowerCase();
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('ul.ablist > li');
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( list[i].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === -1 )
            list[i].style.display = 'none';
        else
            list[i].style.display = 'block';
    }

    console.log('Time: ' + ((new Date).getTime() - jsStart));
}, false );
```

To my surprise however, the plain Javascript is up to 10 times *slower* than the jQuery equivalent. The jQuery version takes around 2-3 seconds to filter on each letter, while the Javascript version takes 17+ seconds! I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu Linux.

This isn't for anything really important so it doesn't need to be super efficient. But am I doing something really dumb with my Javascript here?

Comment: I'd time the two selectors and see if that's where it all is; I know the jQuery selector stuff has been tuned to death.

Comment: Caching `list.length` is one thing, although it wouldn't make for such a big difference. Also your timing method is said to be inaccurate. http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Er, not that one. (Not to mention that one isn't even included in the overall timing.)

Comment: Does Chrome have a profiler or something that could tell you where the time is spent? The only thing that comes to mind is that jQuery could cache things you're accessing inside the loop (the `style` property). Javascript also has a `forEach()`

Comment: @pimvdb Um...I think I can discern the difference between 2 seconds and 17 seconds ;) Funny enough, I got the timing code *from* that blog post, the accuracy problem is at the *millisecond* level (~15ms). Also, caching `list.length` made no difference (you're not calling a function, just accessing a variable).

Comment: @pimvdb: timing inaccuracy is irrelevant when you measure 2-17 seconds. note: you can cache `list[i]`.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: You're correct. Though, caching `.length` *is* a good idea since the length is calculated each time (`.each` caches `.length` internally as well).

Comment: @Dave: jQuery tends to use as much of the browser's native selector support as it can, basically any selector that isn't jQuery-specific should be handled by the browser's native interface because it will be significantly faster than doing it in JavaScript.

Comment: @DaveNewton querySelectorAll = 1ms, $() = 3ms. Definitely not the selectors!

Comment: Try substituting `textContent` for `innerText` to see if it makes a difference. Also, is there a reason you're running the `'ul.ablist > li'` on each keyup event? Is it expected to change? If so, I would use a live NodeList. Either way, I'd cache it outside the handler.

Comment: (1) You can run `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()`. There's no need for a dedicated timestamp variable. (2) Are you sure that you want `block` and not `list-item`? How many `.ablist` elements are there on the page?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could try using `textContent` instead of `innerText` , I think it should be faster. Also timing the list-generation and loop separately would tell if there is problem in list-generation.

Comment: Thanks, using `textContent` completely solved the problem - filtering is instantaneous now! 17,000ms down to ~8ms :D

Comment: +1 = 10. That's a bronze badge ;) @DisgruntledGoat Extra information: The outer commas at `((new Date).getTime - jsStart)` aren't strictly necessary, because your JavaScript expression is evaluated from right to left. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @RobW Got the badge. Cheers !

Answer (score 4):

Another best practice for javascript speed is caching the `list.length` in a variable and calling the variable like:

```
l = list.length;
for (var i=0;i<l;i++):{ code here}
```

And maybe timing with [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I've refactored your code a bit:

```
var filter = document.getElementById( 'filter' ),
    ablist = document.querySelector( '.ablist' );

filter.addEventListener( 'keyup', function () {
    var re, elems, i, len, elem;

    re = RegExp( this.value, 'i' );
    elems = ablist.children;

    for ( i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i += 1 ) {
        elem = elems[i];       
        elem.style.display = 
                elem.textContent.search( re ) > -1 ? 'list-item' : 'none';
    }
}, false );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/MVFxn/

Changes:

- with a regular expression and an `i` flag, there's no need for `toLowerCase`,
- if there is only one `'.ablist'` element on the page, `querySelector` should be the fastest way to grab it (since it aborts the query once it finds the first such element),
- there's no query for the LI elements since the `children` property already references them conveniently.

I'd love to know how this code performs on your page...

Answer (score 0):

I used `while` instead of `for` and did some minor improvements. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/6GMDQ/2/) is the final code.

```
var list = list = document.querySelectorAll('ul.ablist > li');
document.getElementById('javascriptFilter').addEventListener( 'keyup', function () {
    var jsStart = (new Date).getTime(),
        search = this.value.toLowerCase(),
        i = list.length - 1,
        listItem,
        result;
    while( i >= 0 )
    {
        listItem = list[i];
        if ( listItem.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === -1 )
            listItem.style.display = 'none';
        else
            listItem.style.display = 'block';
        i--;
    }

    result = ((new Date).getTime() - jsStart);
    console.log(['Time: ', result, '<br />'].join(''));
}, false );
```